# How to use "find ... -exec ..." correctly to move all files and directories except a few?

Tags: linux, terminal, find, exec

I'm trying to move all files from a directory except some files(or directories). How I am doing:

```
sudo find. ! -name 'myarq.sh'! -name '.mydir'! -name '.' ! -name '..' -exec mv {} ./* .mydir
```

but I get:

```
find: missing argument for "-exec"
```

I am not aware of using the "-exec" probably, I do not know which syntax is correct for the above case.

Comment: `... -exec cmd \;`  You need to terminate the `exec` with a `;` (or a `+`)

Comment: `-exec mv {} ./* .mydir \;` is very strange, however, as it will expand to something like `mv foo .* .mydir` and always move all files in the current directory that match the glob `.*`

Comment: @WilliamPursell Post your comment as a response.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I would use rsync for this task.

Comment: and to a shell script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the error message `find: missing argument for "-exec"` means that you failed to properly terminate the command, either with a `;` or `+`.  Try:

```
find ... -exec mv {} .mydir \;
```

Some implementations of `find` will give a performance benefit by using `+` (fewer subshells will be spawned):

```
find ... -exec mv {} .mydir +
```

Note that the `+` does not need to be escaped to the shell, but the `;` does.